# Was the reduction in Shor's algorithm originally discovered by Shor?

Tags: quantum-computing, ho.history-overview, factoring

This is a "historical question" more than it is a research question, but was the classical reduction to order-finding in Shor's algorithm for factorization initially discovered by Peter Shor, or was it previously known?  Is there a paper that describes the reduction that pre-dates Shor, or is it simply a so-called "folk result?"  Or was it simply another breakthrough in the same paper?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

I have to admit (surprising as it sounds) that I don't know really the answer. I either discovered or rediscovered this reduction myself.

I discovered the discrete log algorithm first, and the factoring algorithm second, so I knew from discrete log that periodicity was useful.  I knew that factoring was equivalent to finding two unequal numbers with equal squares (mod N) — this is the basis for the quadratic sieve algorithm. I had also seen the reduction of factoring to finding the Euler $\phi$ function, which is quite similar.

While I came up with the reduction of this question to order-finding, it's not hard, so I wouldn't be surprised if there was another paper describing this reduction that predates mine. However, I don't think this could be a widely known "folk result". Even if somebody had discovered it, before quantum computing why would anybody care about reducing factoring to the question of order-finding (provably exponential on a classical computer)?

EDIT: Note that order-finding is provably exponential only in an oracle setting; order finding modulo $N$ is equivalent to factoring $N$, and this had been proved earlier by Heather Woll, as the other answer points out.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if this is authoritative enough

Comment: @mebob: Makes for a good Skeptics.SE post =P

Comment: So... Shor's not sure?

Comment: @PeterShor : $\:$ I figure I should mention [this question](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/32077/6973), in case you hadn't seen it. $\hspace{.99 in}$

Comment: @Ricky: that's number theory, and Andrew Odlyzko is an expert in that area. I forget how the proof goes.

Comment: @PeterShor : I’ve just reread one of [your 1995 papers](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9508027) and page 15 contains the sentence “It is known that using randomization, factorization can be reduced to finding the order of an element [Miller 1976]; we now briefly give this reduction.” This is from the v2 (jan 96), the v1 (aug 95) was not kept by arXiv. Maybe this addition was suggested by a referee ?

Comment: Actually, your original 1994 paper [pdf](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.123.5183&rep=rep1&type=pdf) contains the sentence “There is a randomized reduction from
factoring to the order of an element [23]” where [23] is again a reference to Miller 1976 [pdf](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~glmiller/Publications/Papers/Mi76.pdf). However, a quick glance at this paper didn’t allow me to find the corresponding reduction, but the reduction to φ.

Comment: @Frédéric Grosshans: Actually, I think it's quite likely that Andrew Odlyzko pointed that reference out to me.

Answer (score 54):

The random reduction from factorization to order-finding (mod N) was very well known to people working in number theory algorithms in the late 1970's and early 1980's.  Indeed, it appears in a paper of Heather Woll, [Reductions among number theoretic problems, Information and Computation 72 (1987) 167-179](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0890540187900307), and Eric Bach and I knew it before then.

I am mystified why Peter Shor says that order-finding is "provably exponential on a classical computer".  If one knows the factorization of N and also $\varphi(N)$ (both computable in sub exponential time) and one works modulo each prime power, one can find orders.

Comment: Order-finding for an oracle function for which all you can do is: given $k, n$, find $f^k(n)$ is provably exponential. This is all you need to use on a quantum computer.

Comment: I suspected you had a much more restricted model of computation in mind.   But -- as I'm sure you know -- the particular problem of order-finding mod N is quite different.  So in fact, it's quite plausible people would have been thinking about the reduction of this specific problem to and from factoring.

Comment: Heather Woll cites [1] as source for the reduction from factorization to order finding, but neither the Princeton engineering library nor Princeton Computer Science departement has a copy. (I’d be interested to find one, btw) 
[1] LONG. D. (1981) “Random Equivalence of Factorization and Computation of Orders,”
Technical Report 284, Princeton University, Department of Electrical Engineering and Computer Science, April.

Comment: I have a copy and can send it to you if you send me your e-mail address.